# spring-boot application command line running issue

Tags: java, windows, spring-boot, command-line, command-prompt

I am running a spring boot application jar on a windows command prompt.
2.1.3.RELEASE is parent dependency for the application.
My application does not show any logs printing on command prompt after some time. Kind of becoming unresponsive and giving effect as the application is paused/not functioning. If I hit 'Ctrl + C' then it starts working again.
Does anyone experience this? please help

Answer (score 0):

Can you try performing the following :

1. Check `netstat -ano` to see if the springboot application has an open
   connection   (check port as specified).If you don't find the port
   being exposed then your application is not up.
2. If you have included springboot actuator as dependency use
   ***'/health'*** endpoint to check the health of the application.
3. Use postman or any rest client and try hitting the application rest
   endpoints (if anu) manually to see if logs are getting printed in
   console.
4. Check and verify the springboot autologging configurations to see if
   console output is disabled or not.

Comment: I can clearly see spring log as application started successfully. Its not rest application, just core spring boot application with cron schedulers, at first it runs for some time, print logs to console as well as file then it just doesn't show anything being printed on console like it is sleeping, after pressing cntl + c its starts excecuting again, I am curious why it is behaving like this, why need to send cntl+c signal, at first thought of windows command prompt issue  like clipboard copy or spring boot specific version issue. can not conclude why its been happening.

Comment: Can you try debugging and check logs to see if the cron job is waiting for access to some resource or something ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably late. I have the same issue. If I use "mvn spring-boot:run" to start my app, it would run normally, and after a while, the logs stop and the endpoints are not working anymore. I need to press "Enter key" in the console to continue running again. In my case, I have solved the issue by removing all "System.out.println" in the endpoint code.